# Questions migrated from old Economics site erroneously link back to new one

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, closed-sites

In May 2012, a question was migrated from the [old Economics Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics) to [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/):

[Are European schools experiencing the same cost raise as American schools?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1399/1033)

The question has a notice *migrated from economics.stackexchange.com*, where `economics.stackexchange.com` links to `https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/487/revisions`.  This link now points to the [*new* Economics Stack Exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), and the destination of the link has nothing to do with the migrated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when we migrate questions from a closed site, we clear migration history to prevent broken links. Looks like that was overlooked this time around.

I cleaned up this question as well as four others that were also migrated from the old Economics site.

(As a side note, this is something site moderators can take care of as well using the "clear migration history" option in the mod menu on the question.)